# conda python 3.8 ffmpeg【ffprobe: symbol lookup error: /anaconda3/envs/bin/../lib/./libgnutls.so.30: undefined symbol: mpn_add_1, version HOGWEED_4】

Tags: python, ffmpeg, conda, ffprobe

**Dependencies:**

- Ubuntu: 20.04
- conda: 4.12.0
- Python: 3.8
- Pytorch: 1.7.1
- ffmpjpe: 4.2.3 (conda-forge)

I am facing a problem after installing **FFmpeg** from the conda-forge channel as follows command:

````
$ conda config --add channels conda-forge```
$ conda install ffmpeg
````

`$ ffmpeg -version` error message:

```
ffprobe: symbol lookup error: /home/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/bin/../lib/./libgnutls.so.30: undefined symbol: mpn_add_1, version HOGWEED_4
```

I have also try

```
$ pip install ffmpeg

or

$ pip install ffprobe

or

$ conda install ffmpeg-python
```

But they do not work for me.

Could anyone point me out how to solve this issue??
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to [channel mixing](https://conda-forge.org/docs/user/tipsandtricks.html#using-multiple-channels). If you need to use Conda Forge, then use just Conda Forge (it's a standalone channel).

```
conda create -n foo -c conda-forge python=3 ffmpeg ...
```

While Anaconda documentation might *imply* that one can simply use packages from other channels, the fact is that they don't test for such compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

The [anaconda site](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/ffmpeg) suggests to try all of the below. Do you get a problem with all of the channels:

```
conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/broken" ffmpeg
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf201901" ffmpeg
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/cf202003" ffmpeg
conda install -c "conda-forge/label/gcc7" ffmpeg
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response.
I did try all of those commands but they do not work for me!!

I solved the issue by following response. (Install ffmpeg to my OS、re-install ffmpeg)
Still thank you so much for answering my question!!

Comment: This is a bad answer. Please do not suggest to use alternative labels on channels without explaining the consequences. The "broken" label is literally where we send broken packages to make sure end users don't install them. Unfortunately, Anaconda Cloud auto-generates this information, which makes it look like it recommends using these (it should not).

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by

**Step1. Install ffmpeg on your OS {e.g. in my case, Ubuntu}**

from [Download FFmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html#build-windows) website

or

for my ubuntu case, just use the following command:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

**Step2. Verify the Installation**

```
$ ffmpeg -version

ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --arch=amd64 --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --disable-filter=resample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libjack --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-nvenc --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      56. 31.100 / 56. 31.100
libavcodec     58. 54.100 / 58. 54.100
libavformat    58. 29.100 / 58. 29.100
libavdevice    58.  8.100 / 58.  8.100
libavfilter     7. 57.100 /  7. 57.100
libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
libswscale      5.  5.100 /  5.  5.100
libswresample   3.  5.100 /  3.  5.100
libpostproc    55.  5.100 / 55.  5.100
```

I can confirm that FFmpeg has been installed successfully at this time. But when I run my python script, it shows different error message like

```
ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libx264.so.138: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

When I retry `$ ffmpeg -version` it shows this error again. (I guess it was caused by a version mismatch issue??)

So I go on the **Step 3**

**Step3. Re-open the terminate、Uninstall and Re-install ffmpeg from following command**

```
$ conda uninstall ffmpeg
$ conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
```

Re-try:

```
$ ffmpeg -version

ffmpeg version 4.2.7-0ubuntu0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2022 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1)...
```

Then my issue has been solved!! I can successfully run my python script now!!

For those who stumbled upon this issue as I did.
I hope this response could help and work for you too.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail??

Comment: I posted an answer. The whole point of Conda is that it brings all dependencies with it. Yes, you can avoid the error by not using a Conda library, but I think it would be better to understand why you got the error in the first place.